# How to use variables passed through a method argument in a nativeQuery from javax.persistance?

Tags: java, sql

I can currently pass in a variable to a nativeQuery by just using a string. Like so

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(""
            + "SELECT * FROM jobposting "
            + "WHERE title = ?1 "
            + "ORDER BY created_at ASC", JobPostingModel.class);
    query.setParameter(1, "Web dev");
List<JobPostingModel> Joblist = query.getResultList();
```

But when I pass **web dev** using a variable through the method argument. I don't get anything in from the query.getResultList().

```
public static List<JobPostingModel> retriveJobPostingsWith(String type) {
    Query query = em.createNativeQuery(""
            + "SELECT * FROM jobposting "
            + "WHERE title = ?1 "
            + "ORDER BY created_at ASC", JobPostingModel.class);
    query.setParameter(1, type);
    List<JobPostingModel> Joblist = query.getResultList();
    return Joblist;
}
```

The method is called using

```
retriveJobPostingsWith("Web dev");
```

Could anyone tell me why this won't work?

Comment: My guess is that the value of `type` is incorrect.  But you need to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want a real answer.

Comment: I call retriveJobPostingsWith like this retriveJobPostingsWith("Web Develop"); and I have also tried passing \'Web Develop\' and that isn't working either.

Comment: In that cae, you need to write an MCVE and add it to the question.  (But note that "Web dev" and "Web Develop" are different values ... so you shouldn't expect to get the same result from the queries!)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out I actually did call it using web dev. Also I was just wondering is it possible to do WHERE ?1 = ?2  in the query? I know this is a separate question but I was just curious why that isn't allowed.

Comment: AFAIK, it is not possible to do that.  Certainly it is not possible to do that in JDBC ... and you probably shouldn't do it in a Hibernate / JPA native query because it introduces a potential "injection" vulnerability.